# When are dead bodies discovered?

Tags: hitman-blood-money

In *Hitman: Blood Money* guards can discover dead bodies, which has the effect of raising general suspicion and potentially blowing your disguise (as well as lowering your rating at the end of the mission). While there are specific "body dumps" (such as freezers or cliffs) these can be sparse.

**Are bodies only discovered by guards on their default patrol routes, or is there a hidden timer that counts down until a body "in plain sight" (even if hidden in a side room) is discovered?**

Answer (score 3):

The **safest way** to avoid a body being discovered is to hide it (inside a trunk for example). Why? **Most of the time** innocent people walk in random paths.

Comment: To clarify: is it necessary for an NPC to *see* a body for the alarm to be raised?

Comment: No, if an NPC catches you doing something wrong (trespassing areas), the alarm will also be raised. But depends on the difficulty chosen by the player. In easy the NPCs will forget rapidly.